# how can I know relative path of a resource inside of a portable library Xamarin Forms project?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, content-type

I have a question about Xamarin Forms.

I'm developing my first cross-platform application (iOS and Android) and I chose to create a Form App solution.

My application needs to use a SQLite database which is downloaded when the application starts from an FTP server. 
If the server is not accessible the app should use a local SQLite database that I put in the portable library.

To do this I created a folder inside the portable library and I put the SQLite files inside. (Is this correct? Or I need to put in iOS / Android project?)

To have the connection string to this local database I need to know its path. How do I know?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

to do that , you shall implement the interface on shared project that will have only once method to retrieve the connection depending on the path on each device as below:

```
public interface ISQLite
{
    SQLiteConnection GetConnection();
}
```

and implement this interface  on each project -for Android:

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (SQLite_Android))]

namespace GenYouth.Droid
{
    public class SQLite_Android : ISQLite
    {
        public SQLite_Android ()
        {
        }

        #region ISQLite implementation
        public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection ()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "db_Name.db3";
            string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);

            // This is where we copy in the prepopulated database
            Console.WriteLine (path);
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
            /*
            var s = Forms.Context.Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.GenYouth_db);  // RESOURCE NAME ###

            // create a write stream
            FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            // write to the stream
            ReadWriteStream(s, writeStream);
             * */
        }

        var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);

        // Return the database connection 
        return conn;
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// helper method to get the database out of /raw/ and into the user filesystem
    /// </summary>
    void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
    {
        int Length = 256;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
        int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        // write the required bytes
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        }
        readStream.Close();
        writeStream.Close();
    }
}
```

}

for IOS:

```
     [assembly: Dependency (typeof (SQLite_iOS))]

namespace GenYouth.iOS
{
    public class SQLite_iOS : ISQLite
    {
        public SQLite_iOS ()
        {
        }

        #region ISQLite implementation
        public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection ()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "db_Name.db3";
            string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
            string libraryPath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, "..", "Library"); // Library folder
            var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);

            // This is where we copy in the prepopulated database
            Console.WriteLine (path);
            if (!File.Exists (path)) {
                File.Copy (sqliteFilename, path);
            }

        var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);

        // Return the database connection 
        return conn;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}